# Find data where Price change date is closest to replacement date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Data looks like

| PONum | ReplacementDate | PriceChangeDate | PcrPreviousPriceValue | PcrPriceValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 90358 | 2022-01-10T06:16:17.420000 | 2022-01-12 08:19:49.746500 | 483.93 | 483.07 |
| 90358 | 2022-01-10T06:16:17.420000 | 2020-04-19 08:25:45.122000 | 332.19 | 332.84 |
| 90358 | 2022-01-10T06:16:17.420000 | 2020-06-20 01:27:55.657500 | 434.56 | 430.18 |
| 90358 | 2022-01-10T06:16:17.420000 | 2021-01-20 16:53:31.762600 | 403.81 | 399.75 |

Expected result:

| PONum | ReplacementDate | PriceChangeDate | PcrPreviousPriceValue | PcrPriceValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 90358 | 2022-01-10T06:16:17.420000 | 2021-01-20 16:53:31.762600 | 403.81 | 399.75 |

I know in SQL Server cross apply can be used to get the data, how can we do the same in GBQ?

Comment: Maybe... Pseudo: `row_number() over (partition by PONum ORDER BY datedifference asc) RN` and then wrap that in a query where RN=1  date difference between price and replacement dates will be smallest when closest right?  or write 1st query as CTE and then select from it where RN = 1

Comment: How fast could prices change?  Second? Nano second? Minute? Day?

Comment: @xQbert: data change happens in a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming price change is not faster than once per day.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT YT.*, 
 row_number() over (PARTITION BY PONum ORDER by DATE_DIFF(priceChangeDate, ReplacementDate, DAY) RN
FROM YourTable YT)

SELECT * 
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN=1
```

--- Per comments 2nd question:
--- No need for additional overhead of an analytic: just a simple where cluase.  Now we could keep the analytic if needed, we just dont' use row number and instead a simple whereclause.

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT 90358 PONum, 20220110061617420000 ReplacementDate, 20220112081949746500 PriceChangeDate,    483.93 PcrPreviousPriceValue,   483.07 PcrPriceValue UNION ALL
SELECT 90358 PONum, 20220110061617420000 ReplacementDate, 20200419082545122000 PriceChangeDate, 332.19 PcrPreviousPriceValue,   332.84 PcrPriceValue UNION ALL
SELECT 90358 PONum, 20220110061617420000 ReplacementDate, 20200620012755657500 PriceChangeDate, 434.56 PcrPreviousPriceValue,   430.18 PcrPriceValue UNION ALL
SELECT 90358 PONum, 20220110061617420000 ReplacementDate, 20210120165331762600 PriceChangeDate, 403.81 PcrPreviousPriceValue,   399.75 PcrPriceValue)

SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE PriceChangeDate <= REPLACEMENTDATE
```

Giving us:

```
+-------+----------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+---------------+
| PONum |   ReplacementDate    |   PriceChangeDate    | PcrPreviousPriceValue | PcrPriceValue |
+-------+----------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+---------------+
| 90358 | 20220110061617420000 | 20200419082545122000 |                332.19 |        332.84 |
| 90358 | 20220110061617420000 | 20200620012755657500 |                434.56 |        430.18 |
| 90358 | 20220110061617420000 | 20210120165331762600 |                403.81 |        399.75 |
+-------+----------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+---------------+
```

So all you would need is
a simple query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable YT
WHERE PriceChangeDate <= REPLACEMENTDATE
```

Comment: In the current solution, the result is giving PriceChangeDate as 2022-01-12 08:19:49.746500, how to get only data where PriceChangeDate is less than or equal to ReplacementDate?

Comment: This appears to be a different question/need.  as you want multiple records back.  In this case there's no need for a CTE/Subquery just a simple where clause  (See updated solution)  Note: new questions should be asked as such: not amending old questions.  Why? it makes the question/answer convoluted and reduces it's usefulness as a solution in the future.  Key Point: Ask different questions in different posts; do not adjust alter the nature of an original question.  Refine/clairify yes: change the nature of no.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT top 1 * FROM Your_Table_Name ORDER BY DATEDIFF(SECOND, [PriceChangeDate], [ReplacementDate]) / 1000
```